# Using externally defined constants in flex rules

Tags: c, flex-lexer

I have some constants defined in a header file that contain the max length of certain strings to be parsed by a file parser written in flex/bison. I want to move the code for checking string lengths from the c code to my regular expressions to make things a bit more concise.

Right now I have rules that look like:

```
[[:alnum:]]+ { yylval.sval = (char*) strdup(yytext); return STRING; }
```

Where the length check takes place in the bison rules.

I want to modify this so that it checks for a match no longer than MAX_STR_LEN which is defined in a header called constants.h. If MAX_STR_LEN is equal to 32 than I would want the same effect as:

```
[[:alnum:]]{1,32}
```

Is there anyway to do this without running my flex file through an additional step of preprocessing?

**EDIT:**

The following rule will fail because MAX_STR_LEN is not a literal number, it is seen as a string so flex thinks that 2 actions have been defined for a single rule.

```
[[:alnum:]]{1,MAX_STR_LEN} { do_something(); }
```

Additionally if one tries to define a macro in the declarations part of the flex file than it also fails as such.

```
max_len 32 /* Also fails if 32 is replaces with MAX_STR_LEN */
%%
[[:alnum:]]{1,max_len} { do_something(); }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could deal with it in the action rule:

```
[[:alnum:]]+    { if (yyleng > MAX_STR_LEN) yyless(MAX_STRING_LEN);
                  yylval.sval = (char*) strdup(yytext); return STRING; }
```

This makes the rule effectively the same as your `{1,MAX_STR_LEN}` modifier on the pattern

Comment: Note that if you do the above `yyless` you will wind up rescanning the excess as another `STRING` token, given what else you have in the scanner.  This is literally what the original question asked but it's unusual, to say the least, to treat ABCDEFG as three separate strings ABC, DEF, G (using 3 as the max for this example).  (It's also mildly inefficient, but then again, so what?)

Comment: This is probably the closest to what I asked originally. I did decide to go with the approach torek suggested seeing as it is a bit more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

Flex produces a C source file.  At the top of this C source file is "arbitrary C code" that you write yourself:

```
%{
whatever you like goes here
%}
```

Since this comes out before the generated code, you can `#include "constants.h"` and access your macros.  You can also `#include <string.h>` and ditch the cast before `strdup` as long as you don't limit yourself to strict POSIX (if you have `strdup` in your library at all, you probably have it in `string.h`).

Comment: I have already included the constants header. The problem is the regular expressions. If I try
    '[[:alnum:]]{1,MAX_STR_LEN} { do_something(); }'
It fails because MAX_STR_LEN is not a number and it thinks I have defines 2 actions for a single rule.

Comment: Oh.  Duh, sorry, misread your question!  Alas, no, you can't get the RE parser to do that.  It's probably not a great idea anyway since it means that 33-character alphanumerics won't be a valid token at all.  Any reason you can't do the switch after deciding that it's a valid token, but before returning it, i.e., inside the code that sets yylval and returns a token-number?  Just return TOOLONG_STRING for len > max.  This gives you a good place to put an error handler in the parser.

Comment: I was just planing on just having the parser fail if the string was too long, but adding the token for invalid strings may also be helpful. Thanks for the fast response.

Comment: @ChrisDodd's trick below (using `yyless` to back up the scanner) answers the question-as-asked, except for a note I'm about to add to it, but is not really the right way to go here.

Answer (score 0):

No, the scanner generated by flex is set in stone and cannot be changed at run-time.  Besides the option discussed in the comments to torek's answer (`if (strlen (yytext) > MAX_STR_LEN) return TOOLONG_STRING;`), another, quite more complex possibility is to do the string accumulation yourself with start conditions and a temporary buffer and such, and if more than `MAX_STR_LEN` characters are found, signal an error, but it's hard to imagine a scenario where this is worth the effort.

Totally unrelated, I would think about whether there is really a compelling reason to limit the length.  Once you design your program with the assumption "strings will never be longer than `MAX_STR_LEN`" in mind, it's very hard to change gear.  If you instead start with the requirement "strings can be of any length", the code isn't that much more complicated, but you gain a lot of flexibility.